# LoadTimeWeaving issue with Spring 4 and Java 8

Tags: spring, java-8, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I'm enabling load time weaving via XML as

```xml
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on" />
```

Relevant dependencies are as follow:

```
        spring-orm = 4.0.x;
        spring-aop = 4.0.x;
        spring-tx = 4.0.x;
        spring-instrument = 4.0.x;
        aspectjweaver = 1.8.x;
```

I'm also starting the JVM with Spring Instrument Java Agent

```
-javaagent:spring-instrument-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar
```

And I keep getting a NullPointerException (see exception below)

I also tried enabling through Java config and that didn't help either.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.loadTimeWeaver()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:167)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/context/annotation/LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.class]:     Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver  org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.loadTimeWeaver()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.context.weaving.LoadTimeWeaverAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(LoadTimeWeaverAwareProcessor.java:97)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1546)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
... 11 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.instrument.classloading.LoadTimeWeaver   org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.loadTimeWeaver()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
... 23 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.loadTimeWeaver(LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.java:84)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b1f54b33.CGLIB$loadTimeWeaver$0(<generated>)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b1f54b33$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f990d002.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b1f54b33.loadTimeWeaver(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
... 24 more
```

Comment: Do you have an `@Configuration` class somewhere that also has the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` or `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving`?

Comment: No, I don't. I tried switching to Java Config but that didn't help at all.

Comment: Could you provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I could work on getting one. Not sure if this helps but looking into Spring Context source code, the NPE is coming from LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.java:84. When you analyze that code you can see that this.enableLTW is null. This is initialized in the setImportMetadata method of the same class. For some reason, this is not happening.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.0.x/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/LoadTimeWeavingConfiguration.java#L84